# Ember.js Action handlebars {{action}} do not work with <option> html tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, handlebars.js

I want an action to be triggered when i click an option in a dropdown that I have. This works fine if the {{action}} is placed anywhere else.

Below does NOT work

```
   <div class="permit-time-dropdown select">
    <select>
      <option selected="">Nov. 19, 2013 - Dec. 19, 2013</option>
      <option {{action 'dateRangeSelected' this bubbles=false}} id="customDateRangeSelected">Custom</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

Below DOES work

```
  <div {{action 'dateRangeSelected' this bubbles=false}} class="permit-time-dropdown select">
    <select>
      <option selected="">Nov. 19, 2013 - Dec. 19, 2013</option>
      <option id="customDateRangeSelected">Custom</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

Even the example that does work only triggers when i click the down arrow. Oh ember handlebars, your logic escapes me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first example does not work because the `{{action}}` helper by default will handle the `onclick` event. Generally the `onclick` event should not be placed on each option, instead the `onchange` event on the `select` element should be handled to find out the `option` selected (plenty of threads on SO discuss this eg [HTML javascript select action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2300292/html-javascript-select-action)).

So in order to handle the `onchange` event on the select, something like the following could be entered,

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jukicaxe/1/edit

**hbs**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    <div class="permit-time-dropdown select">
    <select {{action 'dateRangeSelected' this on="change" bubbles=false target="view"}}>
      <option id="date1" selected="">Nov. 19, 2013 - Dec. 19, 2013</option>
      <option id="customDateRangeSelected">Custom</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  </script>
```

**js**

```
App.IndexView = Ember.View.extend({

  actions:{
    dateRangeSelected:function(){
      alert(this.$('select').val());
    }
  }

});
```

In this example since there is no model related, I chose to retrieve the value from the DOM using jquery so the action is handled at the `view` level .